# Android How to "settings" first time use

Tags: android, settings

I want to ask the user for their city/state only the first time they use the app, but then I want them to be able to change it under setting. What would be the right way to go?
Do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Shared Preference to implement this functionality. On your main activity first login you need to invoked Preference acitivity. Here is good article on how to implement shared preference.[How to implement shared preferences](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences)

Comment: When you access the shared preference, you set a default value like "". you can check if it is the default value, and if it is you know that the app is not set up and prompt the user to do so.

Comment: I like this idea. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Shared preference is a good way to go. But if it is a **must** that the user must be prompted only once you probably would like to have a look into SQLite database also. You can store the values in a custom table and prompt the user if it is empty.